# Splitting string on characters, except when escaped

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a few strings, which I want to split on spaces and the characters `"`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `|` and `&`, except when they are escaped with a `\`.

A few examples are as follows:

```
"hello-world" -> [r"hello-world"]
"hello;world " -> [r"hello", r"world"]
"he(llo)(w|o rld)" -> ["he", "llo", "w, "o", "rld"]
r"hello\;world" -> [r"hello\;world"]
r"hello\-world" -> [r"hello\-world"]
```

To do this, I wrote the regex:

```
r'''(?:[^\s"'();|&]+|\\.)+'''
```

It works for all the other cases, except one:

```
>>> re.findall(r'''(?:[^\s"'();|&]+|\\.)+''', r'hello\;world')
['hello\\', 'world']
```

How can I modify the regex to get the expected result?

I'd prefer not to use `re.split()`; the regex above is part of a much larger regex used for tokenizing a programming language using `.findall()`.

Comment: Try [`(?:\\.|[^\\"'();|&\s])+`](https://regex101.com/r/BChPHC/4). Your `[^\s"'();|&]+` pattern part grabs the ``\`` and then ``\\.`` can't correctly match the escaped char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! Can you post it as an answer and explain the mistake that I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `[^\s"'();|&]+` pattern part grabs the `\` and then `\\.` can't correctly match the escaped char.

You may use

```
(?:\\.|[^\s"'();|&\\])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BChPHC/4)

Here, the pattern matches 1 or more repetitions of any escaped char (if you use `re.DOTALL` or `re.S`, even including line break chars), or any char other than whitespace, `"`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `|`, `&` or `\`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/sg584O):

```
import re
strs = ['hello-world', r'hello;world ', r'he(llo)(w|o rld)', r'hello\;world',r'hello\-world ']
for s in strs:
    res = re.findall(r'''(?:\\.|[^\s"'();|&\\])+''', s)
    for val in res:
        print(val)
    print("-------------")
```

Output:

```
hello-world
-------------
hello
world
-------------
he
llo
w
o
rld
-------------
hello\;world
-------------
hello\-world
-------------
```